# Usual git workflow for a website with single functionality and two layouts

Tags: git, git-workflow

I have a client that has a website which design is switched depending of the season (summer/winder). So basically it is the same functionality, but two versions of the template related files (css, JS, images etc.) I wonder what is the usual git workflow in such situations? I guess i need two branches, one for each design, but how to keep other files the same? Do I need to create submodule? If not, how to edit small file on both branches at once when i change something and that change needs to be commited to both branches?

Comment: What are you using for source control now and how are you managing the changes?

Comment: using git (mentioned in the caption) on a bitbucket account.

Comment: I guess you should create 3 projects : one main git repository for your main site, and two other for your themes (and have a command that can import one of the themes inside the main git repository). The themes shouldn't be in the same version control as the rest, as they seem to be completely separated.

Comment: what are you even trying to do?  Ofcourse you can do this via git , but just keep it for what its orginally meant to handle. Use two folders like summer and winter , keep the file name same since website is quiet simillar and just load files from 1 of them. You can even use 1 single css file to load other css files. And infact tbh summer and winter are far apart , you can do this manually per 5-6 months.

Comment: Ok, so you're using git now, how are you handling the theme switching currently?  Is that process not working for you?

Answer (score 1):

Git is a tool to manage the source of **one thing**, and it is usually best practice to not put to many different things inside a git repository. For example, If you create a module that gives the possibility to add a payment method, create a new project for that (a git repository).

If the framework / CMS you use doesn't support having multiple themes installed and selecting one of them, you should consider the themes as being separate things, and separate them from the main project (into separate modules).

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue of overall architecture, not one of source control (ab)use.  Trust me, you don't want multiple concurrent development streams.  All it will do is create headache.

Consider instead an abstraction which would allow you to factor the common resources out and enable a method of easily switching themes.  Consider using something like Less or Sass to help.